# Run dockerd.exe to start Docker daemon

Tags: docker, daemon

I know that in order to run Docker daemon, I should stop Docker Window and run dockerd.exe in resources folder. However when I want to execute it by command prompt, I get the error below:

```
time="2020-09-10T15:22:48.798108400+04:30" level=info msg="Starting up"
failed to start daemon: a required service is not installed, ensure the Containers feature is 
installed: Access is denied.
```

can someone help me how to solve the problem or suggest other ways to run Docker daemon?

Comment: When you say "stop Docker", that sounds like the daemon was already running?

Comment: You are doing this on windows? Which `resources` folder are you talking about?

Comment: what I meant was Docker Desktop. I shout it done and tried to execute docker daemon

Comment: yes on windows. in the Docker folder inside program files

Comment: Why would you do this?

Comment: I want to run a crypto currency node on my labtop. it says I have to run Docker daemon.

Comment: Post the link to whaetver tutorial/documentation you're using in the question, as well as information on your current Docker for Windows setup and output of `docker version`.

Answer (score 5):

Download docker.exe (cli) and dockerd.exe (service) to a local folder. Add the folder to path. Add the folder to $PATH, in environment variables. in the example below C:\Docker\

https://download.docker.com/win/static/stable/x86_64/

Create a new user group under "Edit local users and group". Name is docker-users or update the Json file below. Add anyone who needs to run docker to this group.

Create a new config file daemon.json

```
{
                "group": "docker-users",
}
```

Run this in powershell as administrator

```
New-Service -Name Docker -BinaryPathName "C:\docker\dockerd.exe  --run-service --config-file C:\docker\daemon.json" -DisplayName "Docker Engine" -StartupType "Automatic"
```

Bonus: Older Docker-compose cli is available here,
https://github.com/docker/compose/releases

NOTE: I had some issues with the service starting up automatically after reboot.

Answer (score -1):

Admin access is needed to run Docker Service